# Account Merge Restrictions: Number of Accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

According to the [merging accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) it is stated that if you have two accounts that you would like to merge then do this. I also searched other various meta.stackexchange.com posts using the **search** function but I cannot find much that states anything about **merging more than two SE accounts**.

**Question:** Is it technically possible to merge more than two accounts on SE regardless if they are from the same community or not, and are there any restrictions on this type of operation otherwise (see below example)?

**Example:** I wasn't sure if there was a maximum number of merges allowed per account, or a time period you need to let lapse before you'll be able to merge more than two if that's allowed.

Comment: Why can't you ask to merge 2, then some time later (after the merge) ask to merge 2 more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of accounts that can be merged, or how frequently they can be merged.

However, the team require you to prove that you are the owner of any accounts you want merging, and reserve the right not to merge the accounts.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish Some people tend to frown on others running multiple accounts, so that may be it. *shrug* Who knows.