# Merging accounts and the 200 daily reputation limitation

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

### Some initial context

A while back ago when I started using SE communities, I found out about the [200 point daily rep limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268901/why-is-there-a-daily-reputation-limit-of-200-points) excluding awarded bounties, etc.

Later on as time passed I found out about people having more than one account and those accounts having the ability to be merged.

I don't have two accounts or anything but always thought of this functionality as being a potential loophole to circumvent the 200 point reputation limit if manipulated accordingly.

I asked the question about "[Account Merge Restrictions: Number of Accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275748/account-merge-restrictions-number-of-accounts)" back then and even got the comment response from [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear) so I accepted [this as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275748/account-merge-restrictions-number-of-accounts/275749#275749).

---

### Some question context

Because the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275748/account-merge-restrictions-number-of-accounts/275749#275749) states:

> There is no limit to the number of accounts that can be merged, or
>   how frequently they can be merged
>
> However, the team require you to prove that you are the owner of any
>   accounts you want merging, and reserve the right not to merge the
>   accounts.

Let's assume the "team" is satisfied with an account merge request and
determines that the requested accounts are eligible to be merged.

### Question

If both accounts each reached their 200 point daily reputation limit on the same one day in which both accounts existed and gained reputation, would the merge operation see this or not, and/or would it allow or not allow the reputation to be merged over for those same days or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A merge recalculates reputation from scratch as if there were never two accounts involved in the first place. If the rep cap was reached on either account, it'll be in place after on the combined account and the usual cap rules will apply.

Comment: So this means if both accounts each had 200 **on the same day** and all was **100% limit rep** with no bounties or accepted awards, when both accounts are merged for *this same day*, the merged account will only get 200 reputation awarded for that same day and not 400, correct? Trying to make it plain and simple to understand so just want to be sure.

Comment: @Facebook That's correct.